# sliding/fading header plugin or approach suggestion

Tags: plugins, functions, jquery, headers

i need advice in implementing rotating header (has fade or slide effect) in my theme. I'm building a theme based on Thematic and I'm looking for a good approach on how to implement the header. I have 2 option, I can use a Plug or I can inject the header in my functions.php. Help me decide on best way to do it.

The are Pros and Cons on its approach,

**Plugin Pros**: Easy to Install--no codes needed, client friendly-has an admin interface,
**Plugin Cons**: not usually what you looking for.. sometime you you just work on what's available out there..

**functions.php Pros** -- You have full control of the design.
**functions Cons**: no admin interface -- it would be hard for clients to update.

**Header Example:**

**www[dot]haardtline[dot]de** - (blind effect)

**www[dot]sweetsinthecitychicago[dot]com** - (fade effect )

**www[dot]collaborative-coaching[dot]com** - (sliding effect)

I'm looking for an approach where i can re-use it to other project. where I can just tweak the dimensions and effect. For the clients it's easy for them to maintain.

---

I apologize for confusion

The simplest question I could think is. How do you do it on your client? What is the best and well used approach...

Do you use a plugin? what plugin?

or code it? (in coding it, my one problem is the admin interface, I need my functions.php to generate an admin interface where user can easily upload images and set some settings.)

Thanks!

Comment: You described advantages and disadvantages accurately, I am not sure what additional information are you looking for?..

Comment: I'm using cycle as well. For the admin interface I add another column on the media page with a button which if clicked will add the appropriate attachment ID in a option. Then in the front end I retrieve that option and display the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find using custom post types in Wordpress is the easiest way to achieve this. I have used them on quite a few websites and on a major record label website I am currently working on to create multiple carousels with relationships throughout the site.

I would recommend a post type UI tool like [Easy Post Types](http://www.wpeasyposttypes.com/) to create custom post types and then use features like "featured thumbnail image" and custom fields to create simple carousels that can be accessed by get_posts, query_posts and creating a new instance of WP_query.

Comment: sorry for the confusion dwayne. I'm familiar with jQuary Cycle and had used that with some project. But I'm looking for an approach in building a theme, whether i would use a plugin or would code it. If It's a plugin, I would need a recommendation. If I have to code it, what are some best practices to do it.

Comment: Oh, well there are many plugins out there that do what you ask. On a project I am currently working on I built my own simple solution instead. You simply create a new custom post type called Carousel or whatever using a post type creation plugin, I use Easy Post Types and then you load all posts using get_posts() from that post type. The custom post type approach allows you to add in custom fields, custom taxonomies and other cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For a [kind of] client I had coded custom widget in jQuery Cycle, which theme was already using.

For myself I have bunch of code that mines queried posts for images and generates markup with callback so it can be ised with different JS for presentation. No admin interface.

I'd check off-the-shelf up plugins first, but that mostly because I am not so good with coding admin interfaces myself.

Answer (score 0):

i tend to do plugins since i want to be able to use my code in other sites without recoding it or copy pasting it, if you want to look professional it is the way to go. Although clients usually dont have the high standards that coders tend to have.

In the long run building admin interfaces really pays off. You will get a good library with functions and scripts that will allow you to build these things within a day. Just by slinging some scripts together.

I build my own media library and I use that for clients but you can use any gallery out  there. Just dig in the code and take what you need its open source. Just don't forget the credit!!